# How do you perform selection sort on a struct in C?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have a program that deals with a student schedule. Section, Title, and Teacher are stored in an array of the struct ClassInfo called ClassCollection[]. One of the options is to add a class. After the class has been added, the classes are supposed to be sorted based on the title. Although this function utilizes the C++ operation "cin", the program is supposed to be primarily written in C. This is what I have for the add() function. The entering of the information was already written for me. I'm just supposed to sort it.

```
void class_add() {
    //check if we have room in the array
    if(nextIndex < MAX_CLASSES)
    {
        ... //Input code

        int xMin,x,y;

        for(y=0;y<nextIndex;y++){
            xMin = y;
            for(x=y+1;x<nextIndex;x++){
                if(strcmp(ClassCollection[x].title,ClassCollection[xMin].title)<0)
                    xMin = x;
            }
            if(xMin!=y){
                swap(ClassCollection[x],ClassCollection[xMin]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        printf("\nERROR: Your collection is full. Cannot add new entries.\n");
        cin.ignore();
    }
}
```

If I comment out my code, I can add a class to the end of the array without a problem. However, when I try to sort the array, all it does is change my added class to 0, ' ', ' ' for section, title, and teacher respectively. I know the basic process for my selection sort should be correct, but I'm not too framilier with C's annoying little oddities when working with character arrays. Can anyone help? Let me know if I need to post more code or explain any variables/constants.

-EDIT-

I replaced

```
if(xMin!=y){
                    swap(ClassCollection[x],ClassCollection[xMin]);
                }
```

With

```
if(xMin!=y){
                temp = ClassCollection[x];
                ClassCollection[x]=ClassCollection[xMin];
                ClassCollection[y] = temp;
            }
```

Where temp is defined as ClassInfo, same as ClassCollection. I've been testing this with 2 classes in the array. When I add the third with this new method, the first class in the array becomes 0, ' ', ' ' for section, title, and teacher respectively. The second and third classes become the new information I entered. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Confident the problem is in `swap()`.  OP needs to review it and post if can't find the answer.

Comment: Yeah we gonna need to see your swap function and maybe ClassCollection structure definition.  BTW you are sorting in reverse lexigraphical order.

Comment: I used the predefined method swap(). I didn't write it. I've added the ClassCollection structure. Ordering is fixed.

Comment: Choose a language — C or C++ — but don't pretend to mix them in a single function.  It really doesn't work well.  Is that `swap` function written in C++ or C?  If it is C, then your problem is probably that you're not passing pointers.  If it is C++, it might be taking references, but you've not given us anything much to work with.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've disregarded the swap() method and wrote it myself. I'm still having a problem. Do you have any insight? FYI - C is the "chosen" language - as per the requirements, everything must be in C except for adding the class information.

Comment: If you wrote the `swap()` function, then under the rules of engagement, it must be in C, and then you are definitively swapping the two copies of the structure passed to the `swap` function, not the two values in the array.  You need `void swap(struct ClassInfo *p1, struct ClassInfo *p2);` and the call `swap(&ClassCollection[x], &ClassCollection[xMin]);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing C code, then the call to `swap()` must pass pointers.

You've established that `xMin` is smaller than `y` but you swap `x` and `xMin`.  You'll do better swapping `xMin` and `y`.

```
for (y = 0; y < nextIndex; y++)
{
    xMin = y;
    for (x = y + 1; x < nextIndex; x++)
    {
        if (strcmp(ClassCollection[x].title, ClassCollection[xMin].title) < 0)
            xMin = x;
    }
    if(xMin != y)
        swap(&ClassCollection[y], &ClassCollection[xMin]);
}
```

You should separate your input operations from your sort code (two functions).  You should write C code when your supposed to be programming in C.  Don't screw things up by mixing C and C++.

#### Working code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { MAX_STRING_LENGTH = 64 };
enum { MAX_CLASSES = 10 };

typedef struct ClassInfo
{
    char title[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    char teacher[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    int section;
} ClassInfo;

static ClassInfo ClassCollection[MAX_CLASSES];
static int nextIndex = 0;

static void dump_item(int i, ClassInfo const *c)
{
    printf("%d: %-12s : %-12s : %3d\n", i, c->title, c->teacher, c->section);
}

static void dump_array(const char *tag, int n, ClassInfo *array)
{
    printf("%s: %d\n", tag, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        dump_item(i, &array[i]);
}

static void class_add(void)
{
    if(nextIndex < MAX_CLASSES)
    {
        char *end;
        char line[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
        printf("What is the title of the class? ");
        if (fgets(ClassCollection[nextIndex].title, MAX_STRING_LENGTH, stdin) == 0)
            exit(1);
        if ((end = strchr(ClassCollection[nextIndex].title, '\n')) != 0)
            *end = '\0';
        printf("What is the name of the teacher? ");
        if (fgets(ClassCollection[nextIndex].teacher, MAX_STRING_LENGTH, stdin) == 0)
            exit(1);
        if ((end = strchr(ClassCollection[nextIndex].teacher, '\n')) != 0)
            *end = '\0';
        printf("nWhat is the section number? ");
        if (fgets(line, MAX_STRING_LENGTH, stdin) == 0)
            exit(1);
        if (sscanf(line, "%d", &ClassCollection[nextIndex].section) != 1)
            exit(1);
        nextIndex++;
    }
    else
        printf("No space left\n");
}

static void swap(ClassInfo *c1, ClassInfo *c2)
{
    ClassInfo t = *c1;
    *c1 = *c2;
    *c2 = t;
}

static void selection_sort(void)
{
    int xMin, x, y;

    for (y = 0; y < nextIndex; y++)
    {
        xMin = y;
        for (x = y + 1; x < nextIndex; x++)
        {
            if (strcmp(ClassCollection[x].title, ClassCollection[xMin].title) < 0)
                xMin = x;
        }
        if (xMin != y)
        {
            printf("Swap(%d,%d)\n", y, xMin);
            swap(&ClassCollection[y], &ClassCollection[xMin]);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        class_add();
    putchar('\n');
    dump_array("Before swap", 3, ClassCollection);
    swap(&ClassCollection[0], &ClassCollection[1]);
    dump_array("After swap", 3, ClassCollection);
    swap(&ClassCollection[0], &ClassCollection[1]);
    dump_array("Before sort", 3, ClassCollection);
    selection_sort();
    dump_array("After sort", 3, ClassCollection);
}
```

#### Input data

```
Physics
Dobson
101
Chemistry
Keeling
221
Mathematics
Toulson
312
```

#### Output from program

Ignoring the prompts...

```
Before swap: 3
0: Physics      : Dobson       : 101
1: Chemistry    : Keeling      : 221
2: Mathematics  : Toulson      : 312
After swap: 3
0: Chemistry    : Keeling      : 221
1: Physics      : Dobson       : 101
2: Mathematics  : Toulson      : 312
Before sort: 3
0: Physics      : Dobson       : 101
1: Chemistry    : Keeling      : 221
2: Mathematics  : Toulson      : 312
Swap(0,1)
Swap(1,2)
After sort: 3
0: Chemistry    : Keeling      : 221
1: Mathematics  : Toulson      : 312
2: Physics      : Dobson       : 101
```

Comment: Thank you for that code and for putting so much time into this question. A few modifications to fit my code, but it works perfectly.